# How to add multiple different columns of excel using Apache POI & Java

Tags: java, parsing, apache-poi

I need to generate `CodeKey` that is combination of `two columns` of excel value and values in those columns can be `Boolean`, `String`, `Numeric` or combination of all of those.

Now I can go through `if/else loop` and check for every condition but what would be an efficient way of doing this.

**For Example:**

If i have `ExCode = 7V` and `PrCode = A:` then my CodeKey should be `7VA:`

```
 ExCode  PrCode
 6D:     A:
 6R      TR
 7V      6K
```

And all i want to do is generate CodeKey as `6D:A:`, `6RTR` and `7V6K` respectively.

Don't want to do something like:

```
 if(ExCodeCellValue.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING &&
           PrCodeCellValue.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
            System.out.println("Combined String Values: "+ExCodeCellValue.getStringValue()+PrCodeCellValue.getStringValue());
        }
```

As there would be lots of `if/else` unnecessary stuffs to generate codeKey, any other efficient solution of doing this or is there any `api` in `POI` that would be useful for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use [DataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29) which will give you a string that matches what Excel shows for a cell.

With that, you could would look something like (Assuming the ExCode is the 3rd column, PrCode in the 4th)

```
// Do this once
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

// Once per row
for (Row row : sheet) {
  String exCode = formatter.formatCellValue( row.getCell(2) );
  String prCode = formatter.formatCellValue( row.getCell(3) );

  Cell code = row.createCell(4, Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
  code.setCellValue(exCode + prCode);
}
```